# Why do I need to provide an Amazon S3 bucket while choosing Amazon Redshift as destination?

Tags: amazon-kinesis-firehose

Why does kinesis firehose need to put data in the s3 bucket first before applying copy command to put the data into Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

The S3 location is the intermediate location from where the copy command picks up the data file to be loaded. See the link here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html#redshift-s3-bucket

Other than just being a path for the data file, the s3 location is used for storing the menifest files. These files contains a list of file names to be loaded. You will also find firehose has created sub folders based on a interval.

Comment: Kinesis firhose can not directly Send data to redshifts without putting this in intermediate se?

Comment: You need the bucket..Please mark my answer as useful if it's so.